# Spring integration JMS dropping random messages during reading?

Tags: spring, jms, spring-integration

I have a production application that seems to be losing messages intermittently.  One example that I have identified is the sending system logs 3 messages that are sent milliseconds apart.  The receiving system logs that it got message 1 and message 3...but not message 2.  The queue's depth is 0.  I see no errors in the logs of the application that reads the messages to indicate something bad happened.

I have verified that there are no other "rogue" clients creating a race condition for reading messages.

Here is my configuration; we have a primary and secondary/failover queue...

```
<bean id="primaryProficiencyInboundQueue" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue">
  <property name="baseQueueManagerName" value="${lsm.primary.outbound.manager}"/>
  <property name="baseQueueName" value="${lsm.proficiency.inbound.queue}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="secondaryProficiencyInboundQueue" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue">
  <property name="baseQueueManagerName" value="${lsm.secondary.outbound.manager}"/>
  <property name="baseQueueName" value="${lsm.proficiency.inbound.queue}"/>
</bean>

<int:channel id="inboundProficiencyChannel">
  <int:interceptors>
    <int:wire-tap channel="logger" />
  </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>

<!-- adapter that connects the inbound proficiency queues to the inboundProficiencyChannel  -->
<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="primaryProficiencyInboundAdapter" 
    connection-factory="primaryConnectionFactory" 
    destination="primaryProficiencyInboundQueue" 
    channel="inboundProficiencyChannel" />

<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="secondaryProficiencyInboundAdapter"
    connection-factory="secondaryConnectionFactory" 
    destination="secondaryProficiencyInboundQueue" 
    channel="inboundProficiencyChannel" />

<int:service-activator id="proficiencyInboundActivator" 
   input-channel="inboundProficiencyChannel">
   <bean class="com.myactivator.LSMInboundProficiencyActivator" />
</int:service-activator>
```

Is it possible that something is failing silently?

One other noteworthy thing is that there are two production servers that are both configured as above....meaning that there are two servers that have JMS adapters configured to read the messages.  I mentioned above that I see message 1 and message 3 being read. In that case, I see server one process message one and server two process mesage two...so it seems that having two servers configured like above has no negative impact.  Any other thoughts on what could be happening or how I can debug the case of the missing/dropped messages?

Version information:

- Spring - 3.0.5.RELEASE
- Spring Integration - 2.0.3.RELEASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing springs to mind that would cause lost messages; I don't recall that ever being reported; but 2.0.3 is quite ancient (3rd birthday coming up soon). We don't support 2.0.x any more but you should at least update to 2.0.6 which is the last release of 2.0.x. But preferably move up to the latest 3.0.0 release (or at least 2.2.6).

Comment: PS: When I worked in the field, problems like this were invariably caused by some other developer having a client running that was "stealing" messages from the queue. "I have verified that there are no other "rogue" clients...". That's what the testers always told me, but 100% of the time we found one.

Comment: It's especially suspicious the the middle message is missing; most brokers round-robin to the consumers.

Comment: I had been thinking the same thing, but after digging through the lower-environments' configuration files I had found nothing mis-configured to point at the prod queue. But your comment about round-robin got me to thinking and I, indeed, found that our batch environment was loading the same configuration and had its logging configured differently so it was not showing that it was reading a message.  I still have a mystery to solve as to why the data isn't showing up in the target system as expected...but at least I know it isn't a dropped/missing message.  Thanks!